# What is hardware stack?

Tags: stack, hardware, cpu-architecture, processor

When processor uses hardware stack, It have to extract operands from so called 'hardware stack'. Is that the same stack in main memory? I think not, if so, where exactly it is and does processor use it only for keeping instruction operands? 
Is it used for keeping return addresses or no?

Answer (score 1):

It has been never called "hardware" stack - maybe that is some modern variation to distinguish it from some software application. "Stack in main memory" term is vary ambiguous, which can mean a dozen of different things depending on what you understand as 'main memory'.

Regarding details of what is stored in stack during calls, please refer to [Calling Conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) and [Call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) description.

You may also want to check similar SO questions: [What is the role of stack in a microprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114047/what-is-the-role-of-stack-in-a-microprocessor) and [What is a stack pointer used for in microprocessors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464035/what-is-a-stack-pointer-used-for-in-microprocessors)